# Swift calling a class from a view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, class

I am a beginner in swift coming from java. I have a task class and a taskcollection class where it is a collection of tasks. I am trying to put the collection into a table view but I dont know how.

This is task class:

```
class Task{
private var description : String

init(description: String){
    self.description = description
}

func getDescription() -> String{
    return self.description
}

func setDescription(description: String){
    self.description = description
}}
```

This is taskCollection class:

```
class TaskCollection{
private var tasks: Array<Task>

init(){
   self.tasks = [Task]()
}

func getTasks() -> Array<Task>{
    return self.tasks
}
func addTask(task: Task){
    self.tasks.append(task)
}}
```

To get the taskcollection into the tableview what do i do? In java I know I have to make something like new TaskCollection(), but i dont know how to get it in the tableviews:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return ?
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableviewTasks.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    // set the text from the data model
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.___?_____[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// method to run when table view cell is tapped
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
}
```

Comment: A sidenote on the Task class. You could make the description a `private(set) var description: String` to make it read-only from outside of the class itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create an instance of the TaskCollection class somewhere in your ViewController file scope.  Then you populate it somewhere else (I did this is viewDidLoad as an example).  Number of rows will simply be the number of tasks in the taskCollection instance.  You can access each task by using indexPath.row to get the index of the array of tasks.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let taskCollection = TaskCollection()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let task = Task(description: "Some Description")
        taskCollection.addTask(task: task)

    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskCollection.getTasks().count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

        let task = taskCollection.getTasks()[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = task.getDescription()

        return cell
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

First there is no need to create a `TaskCollection` class as it's functionality is already build in arrays so, you need to create an array of tasks

```
 var tasksArr = [Task]()
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  return self.tasksArr.count
}

// create a cell for each table view row
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
   let cell:UITableViewCell =   self.tableviewTasks.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

   // set the text from the data model
   cell.textLabel?.text = self.tasksArr[indexPath.row].description 

   return cell
}
```

OR according to current implementation

```
var colc = TaskCollection()
```

//

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

  return self.colc.tasks.count
}

// create a cell for each table view row
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

// create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
   let cell:UITableViewCell =   self.tableviewTasks.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

   // set the text from the data model
   cell.textLabel?.text = self.colc.tasks[indexPath.row].description 

   return cell
}
```